# What exactly was "'dotty' and 'dashy'" Morse code?

Tags: encryption, ciphers, historical

> During early World War I (1914–1916), Germany briefly experimented
>   with 'dotty' and 'dashy' Morse, in essence ***adding a dot or a dash at
>   the end of each Morse symbol***. Each one was ***quickly broken*** by Allied
>   SIGINT, and standard Morse was restored by Spring 1916.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code#Unusual_variants

Emphasis mine.

That's all it says on that Wikipedia article. It makes no sense to me. It's implied that this was supposed to be some kind of encryption/cipher addition, but how is "adding a dot or a dash at the end of each Morse symbol" anything but "slightly incompatible" with the existing system? Something is not being told in that brief description.

Sure, it was ~1915, so they didn't exactly have advanced computers yet, but what's said above is at the level of what a child would come up with to "talk secretly" to their sibling without their parents understanding. Cryptography surely had existed as a concept (if only done with pen and paper, or with crude machines) for a long time by that time?

Comment: Well, it does say it was a brief experiment and quickly broken...

Comment: The wiki entry also has a source. The source article explains the reasoning and context and benefits ...

Comment: and a quick search for your title questions bring up this: http://www.self.gutenberg.org/articles/Prosigns_for_Morse_code

Answer (score 2):

The aim of encryption is to produce a *message* that cannot be read as is. The old Cesar cipher was a simple alphabet shift. We now find it trivial, but when you see a bunch of characters with no evident meaning, you can suppose that a real message is hidden but without knowing the algorithm deciphering it is not a trivial task.

The rationale behind dotty or dashy is that the enemy will see a sequence of dots and dashes which has no direct meaning because is looks like incorrect Morse code, especially if you do not add any space between characters. But it is too simple to resist for a long time to an experience cryptanalist, even without the help of a computer.

On an historical point of view, AFAIK, the older code is probably Cesar's cipher that was indeed used by the Roman emperor, and which was later improved with Vegenere's code for which the shift varied according to the letters of a word (the key) instead of being a constant.

Both can be easily used without any machine.

A rather strong code that existed for a long time and requires no computing is the use of a full book as a key: the sender searches the words they want to send in the book, and replaces them with the triplet (page number, line number, word position in the line). If the message is short enough and the book long enough, it is possible to use different triplets if a word is repeated which hardly hardens the code. But it is hard to use in an operational point of view because if you want to use an uncommon word, it could not be present in the book...